# Is ellipse the only strongly light-connected curve?

Tags: geometry

*Definition 1.* The shape $S$ with **smooth** closed boundary $\partial S$ is called *light-connected* if there are two points $A_{out}$ and $A_{in}$ inside its interior such that all of light rays that diverge from point $A_{out}$ converge at point $A_{in}$. The boundary $\partial S$ is supposed to be reflective: the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection.

*Definition 2*. Light connected curve $S$ is called *strongly light-connected* if $A_{out}$ and $A_{in}$ do not coincide.

**Hypothesis 1.** Circle is not strongly light-connected.

**Hypothesis 2.** If a curve is strongly light-connected, then it is an ellipse.

---

What can you say about these hypotheses?

Comment: Assuming hypothesis 1 is correct, then hypothesis 2 ought to say "non-circle ellipse" or, possibly, be rephrased to "if a curve is strongly light-connected, then it is an ellipse". Also, what happens to light that hits a point where the curve has, say, a corner?

Comment: @Arthur, I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm not particularly-fond of using the qualifier "strongly" simply to exclude coincident points; what's "stronger" about non-coincident points? (I might use "strongly light-connected" to specify, say, a light-connected curve such that light emanating from one point gets to the other point *after a single reflection*.) Determining whether a circle is light-connected with distinct points seems non-trivial if light is allowed to reflect multiple times; proving that a circle is not "one-bounce" light-connected with distinct points, though, is pretty simple.

Comment: @Blue, Yes, light is allowed to reflect multiple times. Probably, you are right about terminology. And you are right about simple proof that circle is not 'one-bounce' light-connected (assuming the points are distinct).